# Laravel: How to modify notifications collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection, laravel-notification

I've got a function which returns [database notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#accessing-the-notifications) of a user (the User model is [Notifiable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#sending-notifications)):

```
return $user->notifications()->get();
```

The result returned is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5d6548d3-1f9b-4da5-b332-afbf428df775",
        "type": "Meysam\\Notification\\Classes\\CommentCreated",
        "notifiable_id": 1,
        "notifiable_type": "RainLab\\User\\Models\\User",
        "data": {
            "userId": 2,
            "commentId": 18
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-03-05 09:58:34",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-05 09:58:34"
    },
    {
        "id": "2e22e24e-a972-4a30-afeb-0049a40966a7",
        "type": "Meysam\\Notification\\Classes\\CommentCreated",
        "notifiable_id": 1,
        "notifiable_type": "RainLab\\User\\Models\\User",
        "data": {
            "userId": 3,
            "commentId": 17
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-03-05 09:38:38",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-05 09:38:38"
    }
]
```

What's the best way to modify this collection before returning it? For example, I want to remove the `"id"` field from objects, change the value of `"type"` field to `"CommentCreated"`, and add new fields like `"url", "username", "email", etc` to each item. Is it a good idea to add `hidden`, `visible` and `append` [attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to `DatabaseNotification` model class (if so, how)? Are [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) useful here?

Comment: check this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-a-new-element-to-every-item-of-collection?page=1

Comment: Yes, make use of API Resources or [spatie/laravel-fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)

Comment: Use API resources. It's the perfect solution for this, as you should _not_ be modifying the actual notification model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Laravel 5.5+**

use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources).

**For Laravel < 5.5**

As suggested by @linktoahref, It is good idea is to use fractals.

By definition, REF: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/

> Fractal provides a presentation and transformation layer for complex
>   data output, the like found in RESTful APIs, and works really well
>   with JSON. Think of this as a view layer for your JSON/YAML/etc.

You can use fractals to convert data to appropriate format, when working with laravel it is a good idea to create fractals for each models and use whenever it is required. It can accept a model and perform transformation on each fields and return in proper data format.

[`spatie/laravel-fractal`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) is a good package to get start with fractals.

Comment: Thanks, what about [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources)?

Comment: API Resources also good if you have laravel 5.5+, updated my answer to include the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just change the return value of a collection, then this can be done like this way:

```
$user->notifications()->get()->map(function($item) {
   unset($item['id']); //remove id
   $item['type'] = "CommentCreated"; //change the value of "type" field
   $item['url'] = "url content"; //add new data
   $item['username'] = "username content"; //add new data
   $item['email'] = "email content"; //add new data
   return $item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel uses the full class name of the notification as a type,
If you want to customise the type of the notification in the database use this method in your Notification class:

```
/**
 * Get the type of the notification being stored.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function databaseType()
{
    return 'custom.name';
}
```